# PowerShell Script Error assistance

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run the following PowerShell Script. It should connect all pst files in Microsoft Outlook from mentioned directory:

```
Add-Type -Assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" | Out-Null
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
Dir "C:\Users\bob\Documents\Outlook Files\* .pst" | % {$Namespace.AddStore($ _. FullName)}
```

I am getting the following error message:

[image: screenshot of error message]

Thank you everyone in advance for your contributions.

P.S. Error message in text below. I didn't include it originally because I thought it was sloppy and hard to read.

```
At line:4 char:80
+ Dir 'C:\Users\bob\Documents\Outlook Files\* .pst' | % {$Namespace.AddStore($ ...
+                                                                                ~
Missing ')' in method call.
At line:4 char:80
+ Dir 'C:\Users\bob\Documents\Outlook Files\* .pst' | % {$Namespace.AddStore($ ...
+                                                                                ~
Unexpected token '$' in expression or statement.
At line:4 char:59
+ Dir 'C:\Users\bob\Documents\Outlook Files\* .pst' | % {$Namespace.AddStore($ ...
+                                                           ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block.
At line:4 char:93
+ ... e($ _. FullName)}
+                    ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
At line:4 char:94
+ ... ($ _. FullName)}
+                    ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
At line:4 char:80
+ Dir 'C:\Users\bob\Documents\Outlook Files\* .pst' | % {$Namespace.AddStore($ ...
+                                                                                ~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndParenthesisInMethodCall
```

Comment: Can you please copy the error message and include in in the question (as text) intead of linking to a screenshot?

Comment: `$Namespace.AddStore($ _. FullName)` -> `$Namespace.AddStore($_.FullName)`

Comment: WINNER WINNER !!!!!! Thanks a bunch Mathias R. Jessen !